# Evaluate String value in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to evaluate the value of SEATID.
Find my code below.

```
String res2[0] = "40B";
vars.put("SEAT_ID",res2[0]);
```

When i am trying the get the value of SEATID in a string i am not getting the actual value of SEATID.

```
String otherSampler = vars.get("{"seatCode":"${SEAT_ID}");
```

Output is coming as : `{"seatCode":"${SEAT_ID}`

Expected output : `{"seatCode":"40B"}`

I am wring the code in Beanshell pre processor. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Try using this for declaring *SEAT_ID* variable:

```
vars.put("SEAT_ID","{\"seatCode\":\"" + res2[0] + "\"}");
```

Then you could use:

```
String otherSampler = vars.get(SEAT_ID);
```

To get:

```
{"seatCode":"40B"}
```

Comment: "40B" is a dynamic value so i can not hard code it.

Comment: Show some code how are you putting that dynamic value into variable please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use vars.get on SEAT_ID

```
String otherSampler = "{\"seatCode\":\"" + vars.get("SEAT_ID") + "\"}"
```

Comment: Jmeter is taking SEAT_ID as a string.

Comment: did you try evalVar?
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar